# systemd: tar (backup) issue backup.service

Tags: linux, cron, debian, lamp, systemd

The following should make a tar file with the date and after making the .tar.gz file, check wheather there is a file older than 30 days, if yes, remove it.
Here is what I get when executing it in systemd. it works flawlessly when directly entered to the commandline:

*executing: journalctl -u backup.service*

```
Jun 12 14:42:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Starting Backing up folders (/var/www/)...
Jun 12 14:42:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Started Backing up folders (/var/www/).
Jun 12 14:42:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP tar[27620]: /bin/tar: Von den Optionen „-Acdtrux“, „--delete“ oder „--test-label“ ist j
Jun 12 14:42:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP tar[27620]: „/bin/tar --help“ oder „/bin/tar --usage“ gibt weitere Informationen.
Jun 12 14:42:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: backup.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 12 14:42:39 Debian-84-jessie-64-LAMP systemd[1]: Unit backup.service entered failed state.
```

*backup.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Backing up folders (/var/www/)

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/backup/www/
ExecStart=/bin/tar -czpf "backup_$(date '+%y-%m-%d').tar.gz" /var/www/ && find /backup/www/ -maxdepth 0 -name "backup_*.*" -mtime +30
```

*backup.timer*

```
[Unit]
Description=Make Backup of /var/www/

[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked a variation of the FAQ [Why do things behave differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).

In that answer to that FAQ, you'll notice that system has a much more restrictive command line syntax, as documented in [COMMAND LINES](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) in `man systemd.service`.

Keep in mind you can have multiple `ExecStart=` lines, so you don't need to use the `&&` syntax, you can just add an extra `ExecStart=` line.

Your text says your command would remove files older than 30 days, but it does not attempt to do this. In you what you posted, the `find` command is run, but no remove command.

Comment: you are right. Although only partially helpful, stil a good answer, clearing up a few other things.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in my backup.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backing up folders (/var/www/)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/backup/www/
ExecStart=/bin/tar -zcf "backup_weekly.tar.gz" /var/www
ExecStart=/usr/bin/find /backup/www/ -maxdepth 0 -name "backup_*.tar.gz" -type f -mtime +30 -delete
ExecStart=/bin/sh /backup/www/rename_backup.sh
```

This is my backup.timer file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Make Backup of /var/www/

[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And lastly here is the script file called rename_backup.sh which is located in the backup folder:

```
mv /backup/www/backup_weekly.tar.gz /backup/www/backup_weekly_$(date +%F).tar.gz
```

The reason for not opting to just execute a script was, that I wanted to purely run it from systemd, having to copy only two files, and making it system independent. Turns out that systemd has it's own preferences and issues with bash commands, making some of them not work.
Next to my execution, the script makes the backup, naming it "backup_weekly.tar.gz", no date yet. However then the script is called, which renames the "backup_weekly.tar.gz" (which always will be created with that name by systemd.service) to "backup_weekly_DATE.tar.gz". I assume this is not the most elegant way, but it seems to be ok, since this is quite a short script. I think it would be safe to say, that copying this to another system should do no harm, even if it turns out to fail for some reason.